# Setting the value of a large group of checkboxes to "0" if not set

Tags: php

Is there a better way of doing this?

I have a simple form with 30 check boxes.
If they are not checked, as far as PHP is concerned they don't exist (not set), so I am setting the value to 0 as I am updating a database directly below this code:

```
if(!isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
   $_POST['checkbox1'] = '0';
}

if(!isset($_POST['checkbox2'])) {
   $_POST['checkbox2'] = '0';
}

if(!isset($_POST['checkbox3'])) {
   $_POST['checkbox3'] = '0';
}
```

If they are checked the value is 1 so that part is fine.

I tried playing around with this but to no avail:

```
foreach($_POST AS $key=>$value) {
    if($value != '1') { $_POST[$key] = '0'; }
}
```

Comment: what do you do with the data after this point? Is it going to a database? Do you create an object first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
foreach (array('checkbox1', 'checkbox2', 'checkbox3') as $k) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$k])) {
        $_POST[$k] = '0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your bigger issue here is with your form.  If you have a group of checkboxes that you need to validate then you should group them into an array in the name like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBoxes[]" value="A" />Checkbox A<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBoxes[]" value="B" />Checkbox B<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBoxes[]" value="C" />Checkbox C<br />

<?php
   if(!empty($_POST['myCheckBoxes'])) {
      foreach ($_POST['myCheckBoxes'] as $checkBoxValue) {
         echo $checkBoxValue;
      }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always:

```
$MAX_CHECKS = 30;

for( $i=1; $i<=$MAX_CHECKS; $i++ )
{
  if( !isset( $_POST['checkbox' . $i] ) )
  {
    $_POST['checkbox' . $i] = '0';
  }
}
```

But it seems like there may be a deeper problem here. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I went with rfausak's solution as it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the form in a way where you have a hidden filed preceded the checkbox with the same name as your checkbox field and set value 0 in that hidden field then you no need to check it in PHP whether is it set or not.

Here I am giving an example.

```
<form name="test" method="POST" action="your_action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="my_checkbox_1" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox_1" /><label>One</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="my_checkbox_2" value="0" />  
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox_2" /><label>Two</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="my_checkbox_3" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox_3" /><label>Three</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK"/>
```

In the above form if you submit without checking any checkbox you will get their $POST['my_checkbox_x'] value is seted to 0. But if you checked any one of them then it will overwrite the previous hidden value and you get it's $POST['my_checkbox_x'] value is set to 1.

Then you no need to extra check in loop for your table update. I think it's more faster then the checking by loop.

Thanks